# Do Ticket to Ride expansions work with the Europe set?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, expansions, ticket-to-ride-europe

I have and love Ticket to Ride: Europe, and would like to try out some of the new expansion packs (Switzerland, Asia, etc... Don't really care about 1910). I was just wondering if I would have to buy the original USA game first or if the new maps would work with the Europe set. Thanks!

Comment: 1910 is an expansion of the US game so would not work with Europe. 1912 is the expansion of the Europe map

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either of those big boxes is fine.

Märklin is not perfectly compatible, since the train car deck is a little bit off, and Nordic Countries only has enough trains for three players. That's why those boxes are not quite compatible with the expansion maps.

Answer (score 15):

No, you only need **one** of the base games (Europe or USA) in order to access the train car cards, scoring markers and the player carriage pieces. It doesn't matter which base game you own. For example, the [rules for Heart of Africa](http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_africa_rules.pdf) tell you:

> This game is an expansion and requires that you use the following game
>   parts from one of the previous versions of Ticket to Ride:
>
> A reserve of 45 Trains per player and matching Scoring Markers taken from any of the following:
>
> - Ticket to Ride / Ticket to Ride Europe
>
> 110 Train Car Cards taken from:
>
> - Ticket to Ride / Ticket to Ride Europe / USA 1910 expansion

You can also confirm this yourself by looking at the Games of Wonder website descriptions for each map, for example [Asia](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/maps/asia/). They all say the same thing:

> NOT A STAND-ALONE GAME! Requires an original copy of Ticket to Ride® or Ticket to Ride® Europe to play.

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget that [Ticket To Ride: Alvin & Dexter](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/89848/ticket-ride-alvin-dexter) is an expansion that can work with any of the base TTR games. It expands the game in a different direction; adding a giant dinosaur and an alien who can create havoc for those trying to build to/from a certain location.

Comment: Welcome! This expansion sounds very interesting, I'd like to try it out.  However, this answer does not really address the question above. This post would be better as a comment.  Comments (like this) can be left on either questions or answers, however they don't score any reputation.